# axios with ssl options

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, axios-retry

I went through axios documentation. It says to specify the ssl options in http agent options. But for each request loading the ssl from file like below have performance problem?

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false, // (NOTE: this will disable client verification)
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./usercert.pem"),
  key: fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
  passphrase: "YYY"
})

axios.get(url, { httpsAgent })
```

Comment: If you bundle your key and certificate and then include them.

Comment: @LovekeshKumar: can you be more specific and clear?